# What's it called when someone is trying to end a conversation?

Tags: meaning, american-english

Everyone does the thing where while speaking to someone you'll start inching away in order to end the conversation.  Or you'll say something thats a conversation ender like "time to get back to work" or sometimes a joke with the right inflection does the trick.

Is there a word that means "trying to end a conversation" in this context?

Comment: It's called "trying to end a conversation". Is there something about that phrase that doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: Edited post to be more clear about what I'm asking.

Comment: The longest 5/10/20 minutes of your life.

Comment: _An escape attempt_?

Comment: You can use the expression: drop a conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Break off** a conversation

For example, see this [how to](http://www.conflicttopeaceinrelationships.com/how-do-you-break-off-a-conversation-without-being-rude/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find a single word that means exactly what you're looking for.

You might call it "putting a polite end to the conversation", but the way you've already described it is how most people would describe it.

Answer (score 0):

Backing away from the speaker is one way of trying to **close down the conversation.**

If you actively interrupt the other person in such a way that it is clear you are trying to end the conversation, you could be said to be **closing down the speaker.**

Answer (score 0):

In the context of dating, if someone is attempting to end the conversation while on a date(usually because they're bored) you could say that the person is trying to find an **exit strategy**. I couldn't find a dictionary link/evidence/support but I have heard/read people talk about it enough times over the internet to post it as an answer. You could use google to confirm.

Answer (score -1):

What about "killing a conversation"?